# clean software installation avoiding piracy

Tags: partitioning, windows-10-upgrade, software-update

I am using an ACER Aspire 6930 laptop still running vista 64 bit. When I purchased a Dell Inspiron running windows 10 last year I found it to be inferior. I would like to install the software onto the ACER after all I purchased it and have the recovery disc dont think I even registered it. I have run win upgrade advisor which says my system meets the requirements is there some step by step guidline for installing the software? Or am I into a questionable area?

Comment: The Windows 10 license on the Dell laptop belongs to the Dell laptop. It was licensed not to you, but to run on the Dell laptop. It will not activate elsewhere. This is called an "OEM" license and it does not have the same "install anywhere" license freedom as a "retail" license which is one you purchase for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2013/05/14/licensing-logic-whats-the-difference-between-oem-retail-and-volume-licenses/

Your Dell laptop has an OEM license, and this document from Microsoft has THIS to say about the limitations of an OEM license regarding transfering:

> ...there are no transfer rights, so the software may not be removed from the PC it was originally installed on and installed on another, however, you are allowed to transfer the PC complete with the OEM licensed software to a new user if required.